# TAR from dir into 'tar root'

Tags: tar

I was looking for an answer, I thought I found it, but it doesn't work correctly :-S

Question: I want to pack: /foo/bar/dir/* but when I unpack the tar I would like to have /dir/*

So i thought:
1) tar -cvf file.tar /foo/bar/dir -C /dir
or
2) tar -cvf file.tar /foo/bar/dir -C /foo/bar

But when I open the TARs they both have the first dir: foo, then bar etc...

Comment: This is off-topic here.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Why would this not be related to system administration ?

Comment: @lain I didn't mean that tar is not related to system administration. I meant that this is a page for server professionals. Ever seen a *nix admin who doesn't know how to use tar? I have experienced more "difficult" questions which I have answered being moved to another site. By my impression of the behaviour here this is a legitimate question but on unix or superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the order of the options:

```
tar -cvf file.tar -C /foo/bar dir
```

Answer (score 0):

`$ cd /foo/bar

$ tar -cvf /other/dir/path/file.tar dir`